# How is Stack Overflow (the site) spelled?

Tags: discussion, support

I've seen:

- Stack Overflow
- StackOverflow
- stackoverflow

How is it spelled?

Comment: [They say](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) it's "Stack Overflow".

Comment: First one. http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance

Comment: Might as well expand that into an answer @Rizier123

Comment: @Bart If we don't have a dupe for it, you can post one if you want. I'm not much of a meta-answer'er.

Comment: It is just SO isn't it?  Soon to be a verb as in "I could google but I'll so it".

Comment: 'Hive of drones who will do all your homework for free'

Comment: Oh the irony? The answer is the title of the question

Comment: Oh.. TIL that 'spelled' means different things in different societies.  In UK, 'spelled' as a past tense means 'under a spell', ie. refers to acts of magic, and  'spelt' is used to refer to the the forming of words from letters as part of a language vocabulary.  In other parts of the world, 'spelled' means vocab. too.

Comment: @MartinJames "spelt" is incorrectly spelled, ironically enough. Spelled means both "under a spell" *and* "correct forming of words from letters".

Comment: @ArtOfCode: No, "spelt" is correct both [in its own right](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spelt) and as the [past tense of spell](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spell). It's just not the *only* correct past tense :-)

Comment: @psmears TIL that "spelt" is a totally separate word...

Comment: In the United States, [spelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelt) normally denotes a variety of wheat that's popular in health food stores. We would *understand* if someone used "spelt" to refer to the forming of words with letters, but it would come across as quaint and anachronistic.

Comment: It is one of my small pleasures in life to watch speakers of American and British English collide on the internet.

Comment: @DamienH: I believe you mean "speakers of English, and of American English", since England is already in Britain. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not the Queen's English and the [American, international standard English](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/america.html)? :)

Comment: @timolawl: Hah, _"The President’s English"_; I like it.

Comment: @MilesErickson How is spelled spelt spelt spelled?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the USA has New England (as does Australia). Does it speak New English?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Yep.

Comment: It mutates. I have encountered [87 variants](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#Stack_Overflow) so far (incl. abbreviations and misspellings): overflow, overstackflow, S.O, S/O, satckoverflow, Satckoverflow, SatckOverflow, So, SO, sof, SOF, Stack Ooverflow, stack oveflow, Stack Oveflow, stack over flow, Stack over flow, Stack Over Flow, stack overflow, stack Overflow, Stack overflow, Stack Overflow, Stack OverfLow, Stack OverFlow, Stack OVERFLOW, STACK OVERFLOW, Stack Overfollow, stack Overfolw, Stack Overlfow, Stack Overlow, Stack Oversflow,

Comment: cont' - Stack Owerflow, stack-overflow, Stack-overflow, Stack-Overflow, Stacked Overflow, StackedOverflow, Stackeoverflow, Stackerflow, stackflow, Stackflow, StackOerflow, StackOF, StackOFlow, stackoveflow, Stackoveflow, StackOveflow, Stackover, stackover flow, Stackover flow, stackoverflopw, stackoverflow, stackOverflow, stackOverFlow, Stackoverflow, StackoverFlow, StackOverflow, StackOverfLow, StackOverFlow, StackOVerflow, STACKOVERFLOW, stackoverflow.SE, stackoverfow, stackoverfull, stackoverlfow, StackOverlfow, stackoverlow, StackOverlow, StackOvertflow, stackovwerflow, stackowerflow,

Comment: cont' - StackOwerflow, stackverflow, stackvoerflow, stackvoverflow, Stackvoverflow, StacOkverflow, Stacoverflow, stafkoverflow, Stak Overflow, Stakcoverflow, Stalckoverflow, Stalkoverflow, statckoverflow, StckOverflow, StrackOverflow, and Syackoverflow.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

To be complete, I have [seen stockoverflow and stuckoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI5Dj.png) as well ...

... but the official spelling is Stack Overflow as indicated by [Rizier123](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123) who directed you to the [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

From the section *Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name* in that article:

> **Stack Overflow** is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always written **stackoverflow.com** (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply). Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer. The reason I asked has been because I have had my writings of "Stack Overflow" edited to stackoverflow (same with JavaScript to Javascript) by users with over 2k rep, and when I try to address the issue by re-editing it, my edit requests were rejected as trivial, while their own not. Seems awfully backward. I suppose my only recourse is to get 2k rep myself and revise such edits since proper spelling doesn't matter to them?

Comment: @timolawl Yes, get to 2K to edit or even better to 3K and start the proper moderation of all the posts. Do know that the SOCVR room maintains a magic editor script that fixes the most common spelling and grammar mistakes in a post with a simple click. Remember when editing to fix as much as possible in a post and leave a clear comment why you  edited a post. Accept that others might not care much about proper capitalization.

Comment: @timolawl: you are right, [that](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36673634/revisions) is a pretty annoying correction. Perhaps the editor believed "stackoverflow" was meant as "overflowing the stack". Or he truly, deeply, madly believes that is how the site is called.

Comment: What, no "stickoverflow"? ;-)

Comment: I left the honors to you @psmears

Comment: I see "stack" a lot and it winds me up for no particular reason

Comment: I see no mention of magic or hexes or rituals.  What does this answer have to do with the question at hand: what spells are on stack overflow (the site)?  And meanwhile, the on-topic answer was deleted by @undo.  Humbug, what is meta coming to!

Comment: `I have seen stockoverflow and stuckoverflow as well` Oh god...