# Where can I find profile views on Stack Overflow after the recent update?

Tags: discussion

After the recent update on Stack Overflow, I am unable to find my total profile views inside the `Profile` tab. Where can I find it?

Comment: It's gone. See [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive). There's a user script posted in [LegacyProfiles - Bringing back the old profile stats](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/legacyprofiles-bringing-back-the-old-profile-stats) that will get it back.. as long as it's provided by the API:

Comment: Closely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410719/whats-wrong-with-having-a-vanity-metric

Comment: Also, [How is Stack Overflow (the site) spelled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321191/215552)